# Specify local/bind address for DNS lookups

Tags: java, sockets, networking

I am looking for a way to specify the local or bind address when performing domain name resolution.

For instance:

```
Socket sock = new Socket();
sock.bind(new InetSocketAddress("1.2.3.4", 0));
sock.connect(new InetSocketAddress("mydomain.com", 1234));
```

The above code correctly uses 1.2.3.4 as its source address for the TCP socket that it creates. However, it does not use the source address in order to perform the DNS lookup required in order to resolve `mydomain.com`.

Is there a way to make it lookup `mydomain.com` using the same local address that has been specified to `Socket#bind`?

Comment: Why? It shouldn't matter unless you have a very strange network topology. Normally an outbound socket will be automatically bound to the most appopriate address to communicate with the target.

Comment: Usually the DNS server responsible for the domain will not see your source IP anyway since the recursive resolving will not be done by your application but by some other DNS server to whom the query is forwarded too. It is unclear what you are trying to achieve by having your query originate at the same IP as the TCP connection.

Comment: @user207421 I have multiple WAN gateways. The gateway of the particular IP that the socket is bound to may not be the default gateway. If the WAN gateway of this socket is connected, but the default gateway isn't, then failing the connectivity of this socket would be a bummer wouldn't it?

Comment: A default gateway is the least desirable gateway. The longest match gives you the most specific gateway, and the default gateway is the shortest match, so it is the least specific because it matches everything (`0.0.0.0/0`). A more specific gateway knows better how to reach a destination than the default gateway. In any case, trying to control routing from an endpoint goes against the very principle of IP, and it rarely works correctly.

Comment: @RonMaupin This is nothing new. People have been using multiple routing tables for multiple network interfaces for a long time now. It's the lack of API to specify which network interface (or source IP) I wish to use for name resolution, or that the Socket implementation doesn't use the same source IP for name resolution that is the problem.

Comment: @BenBarkay the only way to specify the source IP/interface for the DNS lookup is to implement the DNS protocol yourself using your own socket.

Comment: @BenBarkay If the default gateway is down it can't be used as a route, and therefore it won't be bound to, and if it isn't the most appropriate route to the target it won't be used for the bind even if it's up. You still haven't provided a real motivation for this question.

Comment: @user207421 I have multiple *unstable* WAN interfaces, each of these would ideally keep a TCP connection. I would like to use the same network interface to perform DNS lookup, so that the socket doesn't fail to connect because it used a different network interface that's currently down.

Comment: @RemyLebeau that's what I came to as well. That's why I find this question worthy of being asked.